# combine trailing slashes in analytics

Tags: google-analytics, regular-expression, regex

Inside my analytics profile, I have to aggregate data from URLs when they are on separate rows because `example.com/path` is different from `example.com/path/`. This is a huge usability headache, so I figured there would be many solutions to this issue already. I [followed what this guy did here](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/12/17/cleaning-urls-google-analytics/) and created a filter to rename the URI.

He creates a regex `^(/[a-z0-9/_\-]*[^/])$` that matches alphanumeric, underscore, and dash characters and doesn't match those that end with a slash. The URI is output as the same value with a slash, assuming it matches the regex. I have tried both this regex, and the same regex with the slashes escaped `^(\/[a-z0-9\/_\-]*[^\/])$` as [this online regex tester instructed me to do](https://regex101.com/), but my reports are not updating with the new filter.

When I send traffic to `example.com/path` and `example.com/path/` with the new filter saved, it is still showing up as two records.

Did I miss a step?

### edit

I've also tried `(^/.*?)/+$`

**This is my appening a slash regex**
[image]

**This is my other filter to show full domain**
[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you screen shot your filter set up in GA? The example from Lunametrics should work.

Comment: Additionally, filters take up to 24 hours before being applied. Are you sure you are waiting the appropriate length of time?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your filter?

Comment: @KirstySimms please see my edit

Comment: @nyuen please see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [attempting what lunametrics did](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/12/17/cleaning-urls-google-analytics/) to combine their URIs with & without ending slashes, and not getting it to work, I started to think about the problem in a different way. Instead of appending slashes when they are missing, why not remove them if they are there? i.e. `example.com/path/` would then become `example.com/path` in my reports.

**Note:** This is probably only a good idea if you *also* have the other URI rewriting filter I use, that adds the hostname to your reports. Otherwise views to your index page, which would normally be reported as `/` would probably show as a blank line. I'm not actually sure what would happen... But this is a solution for me that answers my problem: how to combine related rows in my reports.

Here is my filter that I have working (`$` denotes the end of the string and the preceding `/` is a single character match which then gets 'replaced' with nothing):

[image]

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. This solution put an end to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try simplifying your filter to something like this:

[image]

So something like `/test1/test2//////` becomes `/test1/test2/`, or `/test` becomes `/test/`.

Note that you don't need to escape `/` slashes as GA uses a different regex engine than what people normally use.

Comment: Thanks for helping. This doesn't appear to be working. The way I tested this was going to `example.com/path` and in a separate browser going to  `example.com/path/` and viewing the real time section in analytics. It shows up as two separate records. Also, see my edit about my other filter.